# Custom Javascript events on webkit iOS 5 not working

Tags: javascript, ios, ios5, webkit, dom-events

I'm developing a mobile web app and noticed that custom Javascript events are not working on my iPad with iOS 5. Same model iPad with iOS 6 works flawlessly, and current Safari also handles the code correctly. Here's my test:

```
yoo = function (event) {
    alert("event received!");
}

window.addEventListener("go", yoo);
var event = new Event("go");

window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BygSy/7/

I tried to work around this by using jQuery binding/triggering functions--- that didn't work either.

Any hints? Am I missing something basic that I need to do when binding and dispatching custom events on iOS 5's webkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing third parameter, could that cause the error behavior on iOS5? Also initEvent could be used:

```
window.addEventListener("go", yoo, false);
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
evt.initEvent("go", true, true);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: Thanks! Googling around with a bit of your code I see that this is an older-fashioned way to dispatch events, difference is documented here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent

Comment: @BBNyc that's true. But during the time iOS5 was released, that way wasn't deprecated :).